# Use a django template variable in django-crispy button name

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-crispy-forms

I'm using django-crispy-forms to generate a Bootstrap-compatible form.  For the form submission, I have the following code in my forms.py:

```
FormActions(
    Submit('convert', 'Save changes', css_class="btn-primary"),
    HTML(' | '),
    Submit('cancel', 'Cancel'),
)
```

Instead of the Submit text reading "Save changes", I'd rather leverage the template variable {{ function }} which is passed from my view.  Sometimes, this variable reads "Edit Task."  Sometimes it reads "Create Task."

Is there a way to include a template variable in the button's text?  I tried the following:

```
FormActions(
    Submit('convert', 
        HTML(""" {{ function }} """),
        css_class="btn-primary"),
    HTML(' | '),
    Submit('cancel', 'Cancel'),
)
```

but the button output read:

```
<crispy_forms.layout.HTML object at 0x0331C970>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this not supported currently. I'm planning on working on the project his weekend and I will look at this.

**Update 2012/9/16**

Since version **1.2.0** you can do:

```
Submit("button.name", '{{ context_var }}')
```

Comment: k, thanks.  Please, if you don't mind, comment later if you develop anything.  Otherwise, I'll check back at your project site.

Comment: Hi again. I've just pushed a patch that implements this feature https://github.com/maraujop/django-crispy-forms/commit/d9785ec27ccc81f28af9833e5e81fa942f745b3e This will be released under version 1.2.0 this week.

Comment: Thanks!  Very helpful inclusion!!